# Why does the Input of 'react-native-elements' go out of the Modal Window?

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, overlay, react-native-elements

I am working with a form to change the user's name, email and password.

All elements are from `'react-native-elements'`, `Button`, `Icon` and the `Input`.

This is displayed in a Modal created with `Overlay` of `'react-native-elements'`
The name and email fields work correctly, they only have 2 `"Inputs"` each field, but the change password field has 3 `"Inputs"`:
***' CURRENT PASSWORD' , 'NEW PASSWORD' AND the ' CONFIRMATION '*** of the new password.

The first screenshot is of the form with two fields
In the second screenshot, the one with 3 fields in the form, for some reason, the third `"Input"` of '`confirmation'` of new password, is shown outside the `Modal`, which makes it difficult to distinguish it and causes problems when trying to change the password.

[image].       [image]

This prevents me from moving forward with the project until I fix it, as it is a very bad user experience.

It has some very simple styles, and I spend the whole weekend trying to solve this without finding an explanation.

Because I know that the third `"Input"` is Outside the `Modal` ?

I hope this code is enough for you to tell me what I'm doing wrong

This is the Modal component

```
 <Overlay
      isVisible={isVisible}
      overlayStyle={globalStyles.overlay}
      onBackdropPress={() => setVisible(false)}   // when we press outside, we exit the MODAL
    >
***Styles***
overlay: {
    height: 200,
    width: "90%",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    borderColor: "#22aabe",
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 10
  },
```

// and here I show the form

```
return (   // show the form on the screen
    <View style={globalStyles.viewChangeEmail}>
      <Input
        placeholder="Current password..."
        containerStyle={globalStyles.inputChangeEmail}
        defaultValue={currentPassword}
        onChange={(e) => setCurrentPassword(e.nativeEvent.text)}
        errorMessage={errorCurrentPassword}
        password={true}
        secureTextEntry={!showPassword}
        rightIcon={
          <Icon
            type="material-community"
            name={showPassword ? "eye-off-outline" : "eye-outline"}
            iconStyle={{ color: "#c2c2c2" }}
            onPress={() => setShowPassword(!showPassword)}
          />
        }
      />
      <Input
        placeholder="your new password..."
        containerStyle={globalStyles.inputChangeEmail}
        defaultValue={newPassword}
        onChange={(e) => setNewPassword(e.nativeEvent.text)}
        errorMessage={errorNewPassword}
        password={true}
        secureTextEntry={!showPassword}
        rightIcon={
          <Icon
            type="material-community"
            name={showPassword ? "eye-off-outline" : "eye-outline"}
            iconStyle={{ color: "#c2c2c2" }}
            onPress={() => setShowPassword(!showPassword)}
          />
        }
      />
      <Input
        placeholder="Ingresa tu confirmación de nueva contraseña..."
        containerStyle={globalStyles.inputChangeEmail}
        defaultValue={confirmPassword}
        onChange={(e) => setConfirmPassword(e.nativeEvent.text)}
        errorMessage={errorConfirmPassword}
        password={true}
        secureTextEntry={!showPassword}
        rightIcon={
          <Icon
            type="material-community"
            name={showPassword ? "eye-off-outline" : "eye-outline"}
            iconStyle={{ color: "#c2c2c2" }}
            onPress={() => setShowPassword(!showPassword)}
          />
        }
      />
      <Button
        title="Change Password"
        containerStyle={globalStyles.btnContainerChangePassword}
        buttonStyle={globalStyles.btn}
        onPress={onSubmit}
        loading={loading}
      />
    </View>
  )

  viewChangeEmail: {
    alignItems: "center",
    paddingVertical: 10
  },

  inputChangeEmail: {
    marginBottom: 10
  },

   btnContainerChangePassword: {
    width: "95%"
  },
```

Comment: Please add all of the CSS applied. It seems like `modal` height is fixed.

Comment: Thanks  @random What a schoolboy mistake. Of course the `Overlay` has its own style, and it does indeed have a `Height` of 200.
I have added the style that was missing at the beginning of the code, you can create an answer giving the solution and I will accept it since thanks to you I saw the error, but how to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overlay height is set with fixed value. i:e 200px. Change the overlay height value to `auto`, so it will take up the height as required based on the content the overlay has.

Also, set the `max-height` to the overlay and `overflow` to `auto` (Show the scrollbar only when required and not always). Which means once the overlay reaches it's max-height value set, the scroll bar starts to appear.

```
overlay: {
  height: auto,
  max-height: 300px or [some other value],
  overflow: auto,
  width: "90%",
  backgroundColor: "#fff",
  borderColor: "#22aabe",
  borderWidth: 2,
  borderRadius: 10
},
```